# Spotify spotilocal.com removed?

Tags: spotify

I am currently testing with the Spotify API. Saterday I was able to send a request to https://79777278.spotilocal.com:4371/simplecsrf/token.json (a local Spotify webserver) i updated to version 10.0.62 and it didn't respond anymore. On my other pc (version 10.0.60) its working perfectly. I tried sending the request to https://172.0.0.1:4371/simplecsrf/token.json but I got a connection timeout.

Does anybody know if this API is moved or removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might have been removed. Going to http endpoint directly by ip address a few ports up probably still work. http://127.0.0.1:4381/simplecsrf/token.json

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works, could you explain how this works? I understand the 127.0.0.1 part, but how did you discover the port?

Comment: I remembered from somewhere that the client had a regular http endpoint on a different port. Didn't know exactly which one though, so I started the client and checked with netstat to see which ports the client listened on. `netstat -anp | grep 127.0.0.1.*LISTEN.*spotify` outputs `tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4381          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      32263/spotify`